# Access levels of a list variable within user-defined function

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm working on a function to post-stratify some survey data and I'm getting stuck on some scoping issues. My data is in a list and I can't figure out how to access and use the levels of a factor variable within the function. Outside the function, "levels(data$variables$group)" works just fine. Inside the function however, everything goes to hell. Any help on how to extract the levels for use in the crossing command?

I've gone through the "programming with dplyr" vignette and attempted various methods of quoting/unquoting the string "testdesign$variables$sex" based on the examples in that tutorial. I either get a NULL result or errors.
I know I'm not properly understanding the quosure concept but I've had success with other functions that weren't operating on lists.

```
library(srvyr)
library(survey)
library(tidyverse)

test <- data.frame(
  age3group = sample(letters[1:3], 30, replace = T),
  sex = sample(c("Male", "Female"), 15, replace=T),
  seqno = sample(1:30),
  denst = sample(c("Strata1", "Strata2", "Strata3"), replace=T),
  wts = runif(30, 1.0, 5.0)
)

testdesign<- test %>% 
  as_survey_design(ids=seqno, strata=denst, nest=T, weights=wts, probs=NULL)


popage<-c(10.48, 13.48, 9.68)


#2. Make a function that takes a svydesign object and postStratifies it
stratPost <- function(design, agegrp=age3grp, agepop=popage, group){
  quo_group <-enquo(group)
  quo_age <- enquo(agegrp)
  quo_design <- enquo(design)

  #create formulas to reference the group and age variables
  my_formula1<-as.formula(paste0("~", quo_name(quo_group)))
  my_formula2<-as.formula(paste0("~", quo_name(quo_age)))

  #create table of frequencies of grouping variable
  grptable<-as.data.frame(svytable(my_formula1, design))

  groupformula<-paste0(quo_name(quo_design), "$", "variables", "$", quo_name(quo_group))
  #groupform<-enquo(groupform)
  lev <- enquo(groupformula)
  grouplevels<-levels(!! lev)
  print(grouplevels)
}
stratPost(design=testdesign, group=sex)
```

Within this function I've also tried:

```
grouplevels<-levels(as.name(groupformula))
grouplevels<-levels(quo_name(groupformula))
etc.
```

Comment: I can't read your test data. Did you use dput()? A reprex would be useful here. Thanks.

Comment: @SimonWoodward Thank you for the heads up -- I fixed/simplified the example data

Comment: Should the second `test` assignment actually be an assignment for `testdesign`? When you call the function at the end `testdesign` hasn't yet been defined (unless I'm totally missing something).

Comment: @zack you're right, I'll make that edit now

Comment: The `age3grp` variable is not defined, used as a function default argument value.

Comment: The `sex` variable is also undefined.

Comment: @SimonWoodward Hi Simon, I'm not sure what you mean by undefined, the variables are present in the dataset. Apologies if I'm misunderstanding you, I'm pretty new to R

Comment: Ah, these are names of variables rather than data. Ok.